# Selecting the certain resource files into WAR from the default src/main/resources location with Maven

Tags: configuration, maven-2, release-builds

I am trying to control which files make into the WAR package that is created by `mvn package` goal. Specifically, I want to exclude some files from the default `src/main/resources` folder for each package (I am trying to do builds/package for different environments).

I tried using maven-war-plugin but failed. If I add this configuration (for testing):

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

...my `WEB-INF/classes` will still contain the XML files. This is because `webResources` parameter seems to duplicate the copying process (the above configuration actually works, an files are not copied... but they get copied in some *other* process instead).

[Maven-war-plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) states:

> The default resource directory for all Maven 2 projects is src/main/resources which will end up in target/classes and in WEB-INF/classes in the WAR. The directory structure will be preserved in the process.
>
> The WAR Plugin is also capable of including resources not found in the default resource directory through the webResources parameter.

This is a bit confusing. Does it mean that:

- The `webResources` parameter is a feature in maven-war-plugin that allows files to be included *only* from outside `src/main/resources` folder? If so, how can we alter the copied files from inside `src/main/resources`?
- The `webResources` parameter is a feature in maven-war-plugin that allows files to be included *also* from outside `src/main/resources` folder? If so, how can it be configured to do this?
- Some other option?

Comment: Are you trying to build for different environments with the same mvn package or do you control that by using profiles ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am trying to control which files make into the WAR package that is created by mvn package goal. Specifically, I want to exclude some files from the default src/main/resources folder for each package

Resources from the default resource directory (`src/main/resources`) are copied into the  build output directory (`target/classes`) during the [`process-resources`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) phase. Then, during the `package` phase, the content of `target/classes` is taken and packaged  into a distributed archive, like a WAR, and end up in `WEB-INF/classes` in that case.

So, if you want to control what resources end up in `WEB-INF/classes`, you need to control what resources will end up in `target/classes` i.e to somehow alter the behavior of [the goal bound to the `process-resources` phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings), specifically the `resources:resources` goal of the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).

And to do so, (this is probably not intuitive), you can declare `exclude` or `include` elements inside `resources` element of the pom, as shown in [Including and excluding files and directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html). Applied to the default resource directory:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

And if you want to do use custom exclusion rules for different environments, combine this with [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). For example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>env-uat</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>uat</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And when using this profile, the xml files won't end up in `target/classes` and consequently they won't end up in `WEB-INF/classes` in the final war.

> I tried using maven-war-plugin but failed. If I add this configuration (for testing) (...) my WEB-INF/classes will still contain the XML files

What you're doing here is adding an **additional** resources directory, which appears to be the already included default resource directory. So, whatever you'll exclude, this has no effect since the files get copied to `target/classes` during `process-resources` anyway and thus still end-up in `WEB-INF/classes`.

In other words, use `webResources` when you want to add extra resources that are not part of the default resource directory:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
              <directory>extra-resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

But I don't think that this is what you're looking for here and suggest using the approach suggested above.

Comment: I actually tried excluding files in the "global" `resources` element. The result was that the excluded files didn't get into `target/classes`, however, they still got into `target/mypackage-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. But I will check this again just to make sure, maybe I made some typo/mistake there :/

Comment: @Tuukka Hmm... Yes, please, double check (with a clean build).

Comment: @ Pascal: after re-trying it that way, it seems to be working. Maybe I did a mistake earlier, being a bit confused about the whole process :/ So your suggestion is definitely the right one. I still have a problem of getting `Compilation failure` due to `illegal start of expression` because Maven doesn't "recognize" annotations I use in tests. However, this seems like a common Maven issue and not related to exclusion of files by any mean. I will try to resolve that next :) Thanks for your support!

Comment: Fortunately, the compilation issue was quick to resolve, it occured due to this: http://www.jroller.com/peter_pilgrim/entry/eclipse_compiler_versus_the_sun. So I managed to verify that the packaging goes now as supposed, files are excluded as supposed. Picking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Pascal's answer for right configuration and good explanation of the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558187/selecting-the-certain-resource-files-into-war-from-the-default-src-main-resources/3563080#3563080). I just give a direct answer to this question here:

> - The webResources parameter is a feature in maven-war-plugin that allows files to be included *only* from outside src/main/resources folder? If so, how can we alter the copied files from inside src/main/resources?
> - The webResources parameter is a feature in maven-war-plugin that allows files to be included *also* from outside src/main/resources folder? If so, how can it be configured to do this?

It's the former, the `webResources` parameter in `maven-war-plugin` only allows one to include *extra* resources from outside `src/main/resources`. It *does not* allow one to configure includes/excludes for `src/main/resources` itself.